# query reg dimension of conv2D layer in cnn

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a Conv2D layer with an input dimension of 256×226×3:

```py
self.conv1 = self.track_layer(tf.layers.Conv2D(
    32, 9, 1, 'SAME', 
    activation=tf.nn.relu, 
    kernel_initializer=conv_init,
))
```

Can anyone tell me what is the dimension after passing my input through this convolutional layer?
The syntax of this code seems to be slightly different from the common ones i see.

Answer (score 1):

The output shape of this conv layer will essentially remain the same, In case you find the calculations for getting the shape of output a bit intimidating I suggest a small way of measuring it, I suggest you make a small model and give it the input size and print out the summary.

```
import tensorflow as tf

main_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
main_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,9,1,"SAME",input_shape=(256,226,3)))

main_model.build()
main_model.summary()
```

The OUTPUT:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 226, 32)      7808      
=================================================================
Total params: 7,808
Trainable params: 7,808
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The criteria to calculate the numbers is pretty straight forward and the same is accessible [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-and-calculating-the-number-of-parameters-in-convolution-neural-networks-cnns-fc88790d530d).

For **valid padding** do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

main_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
main_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,9,1,"valid",input_shape=(256,226,3)))

main_model.build()
main_model.summary()
```

The OUTPUT will be :

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 248, 218, 32)      7808      
=================================================================
Total params: 7,808
Trainable params: 7,808
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: but according to that, output shape will be (256-9)/1  +1 =248 right?

Comment: @poorna, you are using padding same, why would the shape be 248 ???,
The output shape actually depicts the final shape after the convolution operation has been performed on the image, you have see a reduction if u use max-pooling etc.

Comment: so "VALID" padding?

Comment: @poorna If you have Valid pading u will get 248 in the first dimension.

I will suggest a run, I have updated the code to include the run with the valid padding as well